# Use reserved word as prop name

Tags: svelte

I would like to use `class` as a prop name for my component, but I get the following error:

> Unexpected keyword 'class'.

```html
<script>
  export let class = '';
</script>

<style>
  .foo {
    color: red;
  }
</style>

<div class="{class}">
  <slot />
</div>
```

Is it possible to use a reserved word as prop name in Svelte?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By naming the prop something that isn't a reserved word and then exporting it as the reserved word it works as expected.

[**REPL**](https://svelte.dev/repl?version=3.1.0&gist=342ec7b9a5833dfeab34984a705cf4dd)

```html
<!-- App.svelte -->
<script>
  import Child from './Child.svelte';
</script>

<Child class="foo">Bar</Child>

<!-- Child.svelte -->
<script>
  let classProp = '';

  export { classProp as class };
</script>

<style>
  .foo {
    color: red;
  }
</style>

<div class="{classProp}">
  <slot />
</div>
```